# UnrealEngine4 Float to Int64 without rounding to 32 bit?

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I want to convert a float (circa 40 bit) to an Integer64.

The problem is that the "Round to Int64" node first converts the float to a 32-bit integer and then into a 64-bit integer.

This will not convert the float properly if the number is greater than 32 bits.

Is there a way to convert a float into an integer 64 without making any great mistakes?

Comment: Is this a blueprint thing or a C++ thing?

Comment: [Appears to be blueprint](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Float/RoundtoInt64/index.html)

Comment: It is blueprint. Sorry I had to add c++ to the tags, otherwise I couldn't post it

Answer (score 1):

Now I've created a custom blueprint node in c++, where I convert Float to Int64. It's working fine